# Keyboard shortcut to close the Firefox Web Console?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface

What is, or how can I get, a keyboard shortcut to close the Firefox Web Console?

The console is *opened* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and *used* to close with <kbd>F12</kbd>.
However, Firefox developers seem to have busted the F12 shortcut, in the latest releases, and now the only way to close the console is with the mouse?!

[Mozilla's *Web Console* -> *Keyboard shortcuts* page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Keyboard_shortcuts) doesn't list anything useful for this.

---

Currently on Windows 7 and Firefox 48.0.2 -- although FF 47 had the busted shortcut too, IIRC.

Comment: Try CTRL SHIFT I  (i as in ivan or eye) :-) C-S-I ... anyway it also Opens the developer tools window.

Recommend switching to an ESR branch if not already there.  Extended Service Release ... they don't "do stupid" as quickly as the regular FF branch.

Comment: Same version, Win7, F12 working fine. You possibly have another application interfering?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas, not that I can determine.  But TG2's answer works, (and is close to what Chrome does), so that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> (i as in ivan or eye) :-) **C-S-I** ... anyway it also *opens* the developer tools window.

Personally recommend switching to an ESR branch if not already there. Extended Service Release ... they don't "do stupid" as quickly as the regular FF branch.  and by "do stupid" I mean less oddities like this appearing for no reason.

If it happens on specific pages, you may be getting interference from the site's css or other tricks to try to stop users from seeing code.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a reference for the shortcut?

Comment: @BrockAdams Ctrl+Shift+I  Open or close webpage Inspector. Source [Firefox Shortcuts](https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Firefox.html#link_10)